# Find max daily value and return date_time of that value. R

Tags: r, datetime, aggregate

I am working on groundwater data (2-hour intervals over 4 months) and need to find the maximum and minimum daily groundwater level, and the hour of those values.

Here is an example of my data

| date_time: dttm | level_m: dbl | date: date | hour: int |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-14 00:00:00 | 0 | 2022-06-14 | 0 |
| 2022-06-14 02:00:00 | -0.004 | 2022-06-14 | 2 |
| 2022-06-14 04:00:00 | -0.012 | 2022-06-14 | 4 |
| 2022-06-14 06:00:00 | 0.003 | 2022-06-14 | 6 |
| 2022-06-14 08:00:00 | 0.001 | 2022-06-14 | 8 |
| 2022-06-14 10:00:00 | 0.878 | 2022-06-14 | 10 |
| 2022-06-14 12:00:00 | 0.88 | 2022-06-14 | 12 |
| 2022-06-14 14:00:00 | 0.873 | 2022-06-14 | 14 |
| 2022-06-14 16:00:00 | 0.872 | 2022-06-14 | 16 |
| 2022-06-14 18:00:00 | 0.875 | 2022-06-14 | 18 |
| 2022-06-14 20:00:00 | 0.876 | 2022-06-14 | 20 |
| 2022-06-14 22:00:00 | 0.887 | 2022-06-14 | 22 |
| 2022-06-15 00:00:00 | 0.894 | 2022-06-15 | 0 |
| 2022-06-15 02:00:00 | 0.9 | 2022-06-15 | 2 |
| 2022-06-15 04:00:00 | 0.898 | 2022-06-15 | 4 |
| 2022-06-15 06:00:00 | 0.907 | 2022-06-15 | 6 |
| 2022-06-15 08:00:00 | 0.915 | 2022-06-15 | 8 |
| 2022-06-15 10:00:00 | 0.916 | 2022-06-15 | 10 |
| 2022-06-15 12:00:00 | 0.923 | 2022-06-15 | 12 |
| 2022-06-15 14:00:00 | 0.912 | 2022-06-15 | 14 |
| 2022-06-15 16:00:00 | 0.907 | 2022-06-15 | 16 |
| 2022-06-15 18:00:00 | 0.904 | 2022-06-15 | 18 |
| 2022-06-15 20:00:00 | 0.904 | 2022-06-15 | 20 |
| 2022-06-15 22:00:00 | 0.904 | 2022-06-15 | 22 |

My objective is to get this:

```
date       max_level max_hour min_level min_hour

2022-06-14   0.887     22        -0.012     4    
2022-06-15   0.923     12         0.904     18
```

with the date and hour of daily max and min for the 130 days of monitoring.

I tried creating a date and hour variables from date_time and have been using aggregate.
I used,
max_daily_lvl <- aggregate(data$level_m ~ data$date, FUN = "max")

This works fine to find the max daily value but doesn't return the hour I need.

I went on to left_join 'max_daily_lvl' to 'data' but it joined all the equivalent 'level_m' values of every date_time in the data (there are a lot).

If I use,
max_daily_lvl <- aggregate(data$level_m ~ data$date_time, FUN = "max"), it of course, simply returns the sub-daily values, not daily values.

Thanks for your advice

Comment: sorry- that looks like a poorly formatted question. First time here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` v. 1.1.0 you can try the following. With `summarize` you can select the minimum and maximum `level_m` and get the `hour` using `which.min` and `which.max`. Note that this will give only one hour result, even if the minimum or maximum values is equal among multiple rows.

```
library(dplyr) #v.1.1.0

summarize(data, min_level = min(level_m), min_hour = hour[which.min(level_m)],
                max_level = max(level_m), max_hour = hour[which.max(level_m)], .by = date)
```

Using the example data above, the output would be:

```
        date min_level min_hour max_level max_hour
1 2022-06-14    -0.012        4     0.887       22
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it with date as a 'Date variable' (and Julian Day as Factor) and it returned the max and min values and hours for the entire 130 day period  for each date. I edited the post above to add a second day of data to make it easier to work with.

Comment: @StephenLangdon What version of `dplyr` are you using? I'm using 1.1.1 (should be at least 1.1.0). Also, did you include the `.by = date` argument and code as above exactly? I tried rerunning it and it seems to work with your 2 days of data. The only difference I see is that I have min_level for 6-15-22 of 0.894 (at hour 0) and not .923. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'll update dplyr.... Thanks again.

Comment: Precisely the problem. I had to reinstall R, RStudio and update packages but it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use `time_summarise()` from my package timeplyr which calculates summaries for any time aggregation.

```r
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr") 
library(timeplyr)
library(dplyr)

data <- structure(list(date_time = structure(c(1655164800, 
                                               1655172000, 1655179200, 1655186400, 1655193600, 1655200800, 1655208000, 
                                               1655215200, 1655222400, 1655229600, 1655236800, 1655244000), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                      "POSIXt"), 
                                             tzone = "UTC"), 
                       level_m = c(0, -0.004, -0.012, 0.003, 0.001, 0.878, 0.88, 0.873, 0.872, 0.875, 0.876, 0.887), 
                       date = structure(c(19157, 19157, 19157, 19157, 19157, 19157, 19157, 19157, 19157, 19157, 19157, 19157), class = "Date"), 
                       hour = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

data %>%
  time_summarise(min_level = min(level_m), 
                 max_level = max(level_m),
                 min_hour = hour[which.min(level_m)],
                 max_hour = hour[which.max(level_m)],
                 time = date)
#> Assuming a time granularity of 1 day(s)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>   date       min_level max_level min_hour max_hour
#>   <date>         <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 2022-06-14    -0.012     0.887        4       22
data %>%
  time_summarise(min_level = min(level_m), 
                 max_level = max(level_m),
                 min_hour = hour[which.min(level_m)],
                 max_hour = hour[which.max(level_m)],
                 time = date_time, by = "day",
                 floor_date = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>   date_time           min_level max_level min_hour max_hour
#>   <dttm>                  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 2022-06-14 00:00:00    -0.012     0.887        4       22
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Your solution does not return the min and max levels as the OP requested. Please update your code to reflect the required output.